# ls: cannot access file : No such file or directory.

Tags: bash, shell, ls

In the shell script, I will have to access the binary logs stored in /usr/local/mysql/data.
but when I do this,

```
STARTLOG=000002
ENDLOG=000222
file=`ls -d /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.{$STARTLOG..$ENDLOG}| sed 's/^.*\///'`
echo $file
```

I get the below error :

```
ls: cannot access /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.{000002..000222}: No such file or directory.
```

But when I manually enter the numbers in the range the shell scripts runs normally without error.

Comment: Which shell are you using in your console session? (i.e. echo $SHELL)  in your script?  (Usually the first line #!/xxx/xxx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `seq(1)`:

```
file=`ls -d $(seq --format="/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-bin.%06.0f" $STARTLOG $ENDLOG) | sed 's/^.*\///'`
```